# Hibernate (Spring Data) to Microsoft SQL - Mapping SQL 'datetime' type to Java 'java.sql.Timestamp' Fails

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-data

I have been struggling for 10 hours over an issue that is driving me insane.

Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types?view=sql-server-2017

The datetime type maps from SQL to Java as the java.sql.Timestamp type. I know the error comes from the Timestamp mapping because removing that column from the query and constructor works.

Here is the @SqlResultMapping:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "PoemMap",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = PoemOutDto.class,
            columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = BigDecimal.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "title"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "category"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "description"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "publication_year", type = Integer.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "publication_stmt"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "source_desc"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "period"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "form"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "confirmed", type = boolean.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "confirmed_at", type = Timestamp.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "confirmed_by"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "pending_revision", type = boolean.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "author_id", type = BigDecimal.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "first_name"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "last_name"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "poem_text")
            }
    )
```

)

Here is the query:

```
    public List getAll() {
    LOGGER.debug("Returning all poems.");

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT poem.id,\n" +
            "\t   poem.title,\n" +
            "\t   poem.category,\n" +
            "\t   poem.description, \n" +
            "\t   poem.publication_year,\n" +
            "\t   poem.publication_stmt,\n" +
            "\t   poem.source_desc,\n" +
            "\t   poem.period,\n" +
            "\t   poem.form,\n" +
            "\t   poem.confirmed,\n" +
            "\t   poem.confirmed_at, \n" +
            "\t   poem.confirmed_by, \n" +
            "\t   poem.pending_revision,\n" +
            "\t   poem.author_id,\n" +
            "\t   [author].[first_name],\n" +
            "\t   [author].[last_name],\n" +
            "\t   SUBSTRING(\n" +
            "\t\t   (\n" +
            "\t\t\t   SELECT ' ' + poem_text.text + '\n' AS [text()]\n" +
            "\t\t\t   FROM [dbo].[poem_text] poem_text\n" +
            "\t\t\t   WHERE poem_text.poem_id = poem.id\n" +
            "\t\t\t   FOR XML PATH('')\n" +
            "\t\t   ), 2, 1000) [poem_text]\n" +
            "\t   FROM [dbo].[poem] poem\n" +
            "\t   INNER JOIN [author] ON poem.author_id = [author].[id]", "PoemMap");
    List resultList = query.getResultList();
    LOGGER.debug(resultList);
    return resultList;

}
```

And here is the POJO the query is supposed to map onto:

```
    @JsonSerialize
public class PoemOutDto {
    private BigDecimal id;
    private String title;
    private String category;
    private String description;
    private Integer publicationYear;
    private String publicationStmt;
    private String sourceDesc;
    private String period;
    private String form;
    private Confirmation confirmation;
    private Author author;
    private String text;

    public PoemOutDto(BigDecimal id, String title, String category, String description, Integer publicationYear,
                      String publicationStmt, String sourceDesc, String period, String form, boolean confirmed,
                      Timestamp confirmedAt, String confirmedBy, boolean pendingRevision, BigDecimal authorId,
                      String firstName, String lastName, String text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.category = category;
        this.description = description;
        this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
        this.publicationStmt = publicationStmt;
        this.sourceDesc = sourceDesc;
        this.period = period;
        this.form = form;
        this.confirmation = new Confirmation();
        this.confirmation.setConfirmed(confirmed);
        this.confirmation.setConfirmedAt(confirmedAt);
        this.confirmation.setConfirmedBy(confirmedBy);
        this.confirmation.setPendingRevision(pendingRevision);
        this.author = new Author();
        this.author.setId(authorId.longValue());
        this.author.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.author.setLastName(lastName);
        this.text = text;
    }

Getters/Setters ommited.
```

Attempting to run this query results in the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate appropriate constructor on class : com.sonnets.sonnet.persistence.dtos.poetry.PoemOutDto
```

I am at a total loss. Maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate appropriate constructor on class : com.sonnets.sonnet.persistence.dtos.poetry.PoemOutDto
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.resolveConstructor(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:482) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:2214) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2170) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2200) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at com.sonnets.sonnet.services.PoemService.getAll(PoemService.java:305) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sonnets.sonnet.services.PoemService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d5a6638e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.sonnets.sonnet.services.PoemService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$503a365f.getAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sonnets.sonnet.controllers.PoemController.getAllPoems(PoemController.java:78) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sonnets.sonnet.controllers.PoemController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5b0f93ea.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at com.sonnets.sonnet.controllers.PoemController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$485f4288.getAllPoems(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
```

The solution:

MS SQL type 'datetime' maps to Java type 'java.util.Date' All that needed to change was the type declaration in the POJO constructor:

```
    public PoemOutDto(BigDecimal id, String title, String category, String description, Integer publicationYear,
                  String publicationStmt, String sourceDesc, String period, String form, boolean confirmed,
                  java.util.Date confirmedAt, String confirmedBy, boolean pendingRevision, BigDecimal authorId,
                  String firstName, String lastName, String text)
```

Comment: Can you please share the full stacktrace?

Comment: I added it above. Thank you.

Comment: And I suspect this the column you're having issues with? `@ColumnResult(name = "confirmed_at", type = Timestamp.class),`. First of all I'm seeing this as missing from the dto itself. Secondly, I would suggest adding a breakpoint within `ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.resolveConstructor` and check what happens in there.

Comment: The mismatch occurs from the actual column value vs the field to map to value. Thus doing so will effectively show you the actual column value, thus changing it to the correct one will resolve this.

Comment: The field itself is mapped onto the Confirmation field. confirmed_at is a field of a Confirmation object.

Comment: The java type descriptor is JdbcTimestampTypeDescriptor that seems strange.

Comment: Well, @Ariz_Kortex, thank you for your suggestion. The answer is that the MS docs are wrong (big surprise) and the datetime SQL class maps to java.util.Date, not java.sql.Date. I've added the answer above.

Comment: Would you like me to turn this over to answer to upvote?

Comment: Also it is indeed kinda weird. I suspect it has to do with the version? Are you using the latest version of SQL server?

Comment: Yes, you can turn it over. I am using the Azure SQL which I think is v12, but I'm not entirely sure. I've used non-Azure SQL without ever having this problem before. It may be related to Azure.

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Weird though I think you should go through the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the mismatch you get is attributed from an attempted conversion that between the actual column value vs the field's value.

Adding a breakpoint at `ConstructorResultColumnProcessor#resolveConstructor` and inspecting the actual column value (and in turn the correcting the field value) should resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

This workaround worked for me. Emit the type for the "confirmed_at" column at ColumnResult, also declare "confirmed_at" field in the constructor as Object.class. You may then cast it to Timestamp inside the constructor body when assigning it to an instance variable.

- Emit the type property for @ColumnResult with name "confirmed_at":

```
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
     name = "PoemMap",
     classes = @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = PoemOutDto.class,
            columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = BigDecimal.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "title"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "category"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "description"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "publication_year", type = Integer.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "publication_stmt"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "source_desc"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "period"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "form"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "confirmed", type = boolean.class),
                    // Emit type
                    @ColumnResult(name = "confirmed_at"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "confirmed_by"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "pending_revision", type = boolean.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "author_id", type = BigDecimal.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "first_name"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "last_name"),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "poem_text")
            }
    )
```

- Declare confirm_at as Object.class in constructor and may cast to java.sql.Timestamp:

```
    public PoemOutDto(BigDecimal id, String title, String category, String description, Integer publicationYear,
                          String publicationStmt, String sourceDesc, String period, String form, boolean confirmed,
                          // Declare as Object
                          Object confirmed_at,
                          String confirmedBy, boolean pendingRevision, BigDecimal authorId,
                          String firstName, String lastName, String text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.category = category;
        this.description = description;
        this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
        this.publicationStmt = publicationStmt;
        this.sourceDesc = sourceDesc;
        this.period = period;
        this.form = form;
        this.confirmation = new Confirmation();
        this.confirmation.setConfirmed(confirmed);
        // MAY CAST TO TIMESTAMP
        this.confirmation.setConfirmedAt((Timestamp) confirmed_at);
        this.confirmation.setConfirmedBy(confirmedBy);
        this.confirmation.setPendingRevision(pendingRevision);
        this.author = new Author();
        this.author.setId(authorId.longValue());
        this.author.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.author.setLastName(lastName);
        this.text = text;
    }
```